# Many-to-many naming column issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to create a `ManyToMany` relation with one extra column (`OrderItem.quantity`). So I use following entities:
**Orders table:**

```
@Entity(name = "EshopOrder")
@Table(name="eshop_order")
public class EshopOrder implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_order")
    private int idOrder;
    
    @Column(name="date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;
    
    @Column(name="total")
    private float total;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_customer")
    private Customer customer;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)   
    private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
    
    public EshopOrder() {
        
    }
    ... getters, etc.
}
```

**"Join table":**

```
@Entity(name = "OrderItem")
@Table(name="order_item")
public class OrderItem {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderItemId id;
    
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idOrder")
    private EshopOrder order;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idProduct")
    private Product product;
    
    public OrderItem() {
    }
    
    public OrderItem(EshopOrder order, Product product, Integer quantity) {
        this.order = order;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.id = new OrderItemId(order.getIdOrder(), product.getIdProduct());
    }
    ... getters, etc.   
}
```

**Product(s) which are order items:**

```
@Entity(name="product")
@Table(name="product")
@NaturalIdCache
@Cache(
    usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE
)
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_product")
    private int idProduct;
    
    @Column(name="id_category")
    private int idCategory;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_category", insertable=false, updatable =false)
    private Category category;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="availability")
    private int availability;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "order",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
            )     
    private List<OrderItem> orders = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    @Column(name="price")
    private float price;
    
    public Product() {
        
    }

    public Product(int idProduct, int idCategory, String name, String description, int availability, float price) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
        this.idCategory = idCategory;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.availability = availability;
        this.price = price;
    }
    ...getters, etc
}
```

And finally, in order to model the `quantity` column I use **this** extra **class**:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderItemId implements Serializable{
    
    @Column(name = "id_order")
    private int idOrder;
    
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private int idProduct;
    
    public OrderItemId() {
        
    }
    
    public OrderItemId(int idOrder, int idProduct) {
        this.idOrder = idOrder;
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }
    ... getters, etc.
}
```

SQL scripts to create database:

```
CREATE TABLE `product`(
`id_product` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`availability` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price` float(10,2) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `eshop_order`(
`id_order` int (11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`date_created` date NOT NULL,
`id_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
`total` float(10,2) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `order_item`(
`id_order` int (11) NOT NULL,
`id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
`quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL)
```

These are just snippets in order to show the DB background (column names).

When I try to view items of a order it keeps giving me this exception:
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'items0_.order_id_order' in 'field list'`. This error looks kinda understandable, there really is no column named `order_id_order`. Which leads me to idea like *it* forgot to add a dot operator (`items0_.order.id_order`) which would make totally sense and should work. *Do you know what happened? Can you see what is wrong with it?*
The thing is during development proces I completely followed [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) tutorial. But somehow it doesn't work. I even tried to use various naming strategies, but it didn't have any successful result.
**EDIT**:
Now I redesigned the OrderItem entity class in the following way:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_order", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private EshopOrder order;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_product", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Product product;
```

I added updatable and insertable properties since my IDE demanded that. On the other hand now when I try to insert a new row to `order_item` table it of course doesn't work. What should I do with that?

Comment: One thing that is wrong is that `Product.orders` is `mappedBy = "order"` while `EshopOrder.items` is `mappedBy = "product"`. It should be the other way round.

Comment: just as advice of column naming. Better to use suffix "_id"

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Yeah sorry, it's just copy-paste typo, in my IDE I have the right version, where this is correct. The main problem naturally still remains...

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that the ManyToOne mappings are using the JPA default column n name values because you haven't defined the JoinColumn definition, so in the case of OrderItem.order, the FK column used becomes order_id_order. MapsId tells JPA that the ManyToOne mapping defines the column and the values, so that the column annotations on the ID field are not used.

This should be:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("idOrder")
@JoinColumn(name="id_order")
private EshopOrder order;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("idProduct")
@JoinColumn(name="id_product")
private Product product;
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Can you please take a look at the edit of my question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by of course it doesn't work - what you have worked in JPA 1. before the addition of derived IDs. You just have to set the basic ID value from the reference mapping yourself - but why would you when JPA will do this for you if you get the MapsId correct as I mentioned in my answer - it is not an idea, it is what is happening and how to fix it